# Removing everything except letters and spaces from string in Python3.3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.3, translate

I have this example string: `happy t00 go 129.129` and I want to keep only the spaces and letters. All I have been able to come up with so far that is pretty efficient is:

```
print(re.sub("\d", "", 'happy t00 go 129.129'.replace('.', '')))
```

but it is only specific to my example string. How can remove all characters other than letters and spaces?

Comment: None of answers contains other than 24 letters, e.g. ß, Ä, Ö, Ü, Ą, Ż, etc. Perhaps question should mention only ASCII letters?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
whitelist = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
myStr = "happy t00 go 129.129$%^&*("
answer = ''.join(filter(whitelist.__contains__, myStr))
```

Output:

```
>>> answer
'happy t go '
```

Comment: After testing I found this to be 0.0029 usec faster than Joel's answer when run as a `python -m timeit -n 100 -s` loop for each code in Command Prompt.

Comment: @Gronk: `>>> Timer('"".join(filter(whitelist.__contains__, myStr))', '''
... whitelist = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
... myStr = 'happy t00 go 129.129' * 10''').timeit(number=1000)
0.02490997314453125
>>> Timer('re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z ]+", "", myStr)', '''import re
... myStr = 'happy t00 go 129.129' * 10''').timeit(number=1000)
0.011039972305297852
>>> `. My point is that 0.0029 usec is definitely within the normal variation for a sample size of 100.

Comment: This also filters accented alphabet characters which might be a problem.

Comment: The lowercase character "z" is missing

Answer (score 19):

Use a set complement:

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]+', '', 'happy t00 go 129.129')
```

Answer (score 9):

Slight variation on inspectorG4dget's method - import from `string` & generator comprehension:

```
from string import ascii_letters

allowed = set(ascii_letters + ' ')
myStr = 'happy t00 go 129.129'
answer = ''.join(l for l in myStr if l in allowed)
answer
# >>> 'happy t go '
```

---

#### Performance comparison:

(I made myStr a bit longer and pre-compiled the regex to make things a bit more interesting)

```
import re
from string import ascii_letters, digits
myStr = 'happy t00 go 129.129'*20
allowed = set(ascii_letters + ' ')

# Generator
%timeit answer = ''.join(l for l in myStr if l in allowed)

# filter/__contains__
%timeit answer = ''.join(filter(allowed.__contains__, myStr))

# Regex
pat = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z ]+')
%timeit answer = re.sub(pat, '', myStr)
```

53 µs ± 6.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
43.3 µs ± 7.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
26 µs ± 509 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

Comment: I found this to be the best answer. It is more readable and it shows how we can use the [string constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#module-string) instead of typing them manually which could easily introduce an error.